# Google Maps Cursor not changing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to change the cursor for the map when the zoom is changed. The change is not visible if you don't move the mouse. If you move it, then the cursor is changed. You can test is here:

http://tinkerbin.com/ENHFSmVR

How to reproduce: zoom in with the mouse wheel while not moving the mouse. The cursor should change but it doesn't. Move the mouse. The cursor is changed.

If you inspect the html you will see there is a div with an inline style that has a cursor property. That cursor property is not changing unless you move the mouse.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var odd = true;

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function(event) {
          if (odd) {
            map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: 'crosshair', 
                         draggingCursor: 'crosshair'});
            odd = !odd;
          } else {
            map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: 'move', 
                         draggingCursor: 'move'});
            odd = !odd;
          }

        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a very quick thing I noticed, Where you are checking for not odd, in both situations you are actually setting it to not odd. Should one of them not be set true?

Comment: maybe the name is not right for that variable: every time the code runs, it gets flipped (it becomes true if it is false and false if it is true).

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be by design:

**draggableCursor**

> The name or url of the cursor to display when mousing over a draggable map.

**draggingCursor**

> The name or url of the cursor to display when the map is being dragged.

Both cases appear to require the mouse to be moving (mousing over and being dragged are both verbs, so I'd assume when the mouse is being moved in either condition).

Additionally, it seems to work in Chrome (with a delayed response).

Comment: you might be right about semantics Erik but this is not how it is suppose to work. When I change the `draggableCursor` for a draggable map the change should be visible immediately. Why would anyone not want that? The problem is that as I change the cursor I also center the map to where the user clicked (not like in the question) and so the user doesn't have to move the mouse at all. That's why this bug is pretty annoying. Any idea how to send a bug report?